# UITableView populating only after keyboard is called

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uikeyboard

I am a complete `iOS` beginner.

I have a `UITableView` and `UITextView` as a subview of a `UIScrollView`.

When the `.xib` is loaded, nothing appears where the `UITableView` should be.

Only after clicking in to edit the `UITextView`, and thus calling the keyboard. Will the `UITableView` appear populated.

I have tried calling 
    `[self.tableView reloadData];`
But to no avail.

I know this is a very vague question, I'm just hoping on the off chance it could be a trivial issue.

**Many Thanks.**

Comment: unless you post some code of the class, its going to be extremely difficult to figure out why you are having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Set the tableview.datasource = self; in viewDidLoad. if that doesn't solve the issue, check if your datasource is returning 0 rows in numberOfRowsInSection method.

It'd help if you can post your code.

Comment: Also try setting numberOfSections to 1. Note that you can set the datasource for your tableView in your storyboard (interface builder) by ctrl-dragging from the table view to the view controller and clicking on data source.

Comment: @Patrick. Hi guys, I tred both of those solutions. Setting the tableview.datasource = self; in viewDidLoad did not change anything. And I was able to "NSLog(@"The value of integer num is %i", [self.listData count]);
    return [self.listData count];" to see that numberOFRowsInSection method was returning an int. I have the data source and delegate of the UiTableView ctrl-dragged to files owner?

Comment: @Patrick. In my viewDidLoad method I have the following code :          // ---  Set the viewable frame of the scroll view
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,460);
    // --- Set the content size of the scroll view
    // 320, 720 got from the xib file inspector
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,4000)]; This is there to alter the scroll view when the keyboard is pressed, could this be the problem?

Comment: I have established that after the UItextview has finished editing, it calls the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath , method 4 times. I also am using NSNotification centre for getting rid of the keyboard when it is done, this may also be a factor.

Comment: Can you actually see the table view cells when the app runs or is that space blank? Try to avoid hard-coded numbers, if I read you right, the scroll view content size should be == to the tableview frame + textView. Do you really need to alter the scrollView when the keyboard appears? Post your code! It's difficult to diagnose without seeing the big picture.

Comment: I understand it is better if I post the code. There is too much code at the moment, and I'd need to pull alot personal info from it first, so trying to avoid if possible? The space is blank when the app runs. Then after I dismiss the keyboard, by pressing done. The  "- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {" method is called. This method is not called prior to this. Thanks for the advice on the hard coded numbers. Where should I post the code to link to ? It's too large for the comments

Comment: does it make a difference if you do self.firstTableView.datasource = self; ?

(best would be to set the datasource/delegate in the IB)

Comment: Hi @calvinBhai, no that didn't make a difference. I have ctrl-dragged from the tableview to the files owner, for both the datasource and the delegate? I presume that is sufficient?

Comment: That should be sufficient.beats me as to what else could be the reason.

Comment: Hi @calvinBhai, I'm after discovering that when I put the TableView outside of the Scroll View, the NSLog debug call is coming up. However, I still can not see it. The old set up was a UiView > UIScrollView > UITable View. Is there any protocol is I should be following here? Thanks for your help.

Comment: For anyone that's interested. I am getting closer to the root of the problem. My inital configuration had The UITableView as a subview of a UIScrollView, which in turn was a subview of a UIView. When I remove the UITableView from being a subview of the UiScrollView, and therefore have both the UITableView and UIScroll View as subviews of the UiView. I can see that the UITableView is populating once the UIView is loaded. I worked this out from the fact that when the keyboard is called and dismissed, it seems to be "running / calling" the UIView, and thus populating  the table. I still need fix.